# want to add validation on authenticate in django form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i created  a login form is ther some thing are already validated but i can't validate is the username and pass word was correct
view.py

```
from django import forms as actualform 
from . import forms
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout

from django.core import validators
 


def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.LoginForm(request.POST.dict())
        
        if form.is_valid():
            # Handle valid form submission
          
            username=form.cleaned_data['name']
            password=form.cleaned_data['password']
             
            user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect(home)
            elif user is None : 
              return render(request, "login.html", context={'form': form})
              
    else:
        form = forms.LoginForm()
       
    return render(request, "login.html", context={'form': form})


def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
       return render(request,"home.html")   
    return redirect(user_login)

def user_logout(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') is not None:
       logout(request)
    return redirect(home)
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>login</title>
    {% load bootstrap5 %}
  {% bootstrap_css %}
  {% bootstrap_javascript %}
</head>
<body>
  <div class="  w-50 container " style="border-radius: 20px; background-color: darkgrey;">
  <h1 class="mt-5 pt-5 mb-0 text-center   ">login</h1>
  <div class="h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center ">

    <form class="w-50 m-5 container" method="post" autocomplete="on">
      {% csrf_token %}
      
      {{ form.name.label_tag }} {{ form.name }}
      <div class="error-message" style="color:red">{{ form.name.errors }}</div>
    
      {{ form.password.label_tag }} {{ form.password }}
      <div class="error-message">{{ form.password.errors }}</div>
    
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-1">Login</button>
    </form>
    
     
  <!-- <form class="w-50 m-5  container" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"   >
      {%csrf_token%}
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Username" name="username" required>
      <p>{{message}}</p>
      <label for="password">password</label>
      <input class="form-control mb-3" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required></input>
    
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-1" onclick="">login</button>
    </form> -->
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms    
from django.core import validators
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def requiredCheck(value):
    if value is None: 
        raise forms.ValidationError('required')

class  LoginForm(forms.Form):
   
    name= forms.CharField(required=False,validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(4,"enter minimum 4 characters"),requiredCheck],widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':"form-control mb-3",'placeholder':"Username"})) 
    password=forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {'class':"form-control mb-3",'placeholder':"password"}))
```

i have already added a user via cmd .i want give error message like minimum character error message in my code.i also tried to parse user authenticate method ,its not working and idon't know it is correct or not